# Chaining results of Reader monads in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

Let's say I have some Repository API where I have wrapped the transactions in a (Scalaz) Reader monad. Now I want to run computations over the results, and save the results back into the Repository. I tried something like:

```
type UOW[A] = Reader[Transaction, A]

object Record1Repo {

  override def findAll: UOW[Seq[Record1]] = Reader(t => {
    ...
  })
}
```

...

```
repo.run {
      for {
        all: Seq[Record1] <- Record1Repo.findAll
        record: Record <- all
        encoding: Encoding <- Processor.encode(record)
        _ <- Record2Repo.save(Record2(encoding))
      } yield {
        logger.info(s"processed record id=${record.id}")
      }}
```

But it falls apart with the futile attempt to map over the results in `record <- all`.

I'm quite new to this type of functional programming and couldn't find how express my intention properly. Any suggestions is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because you are breaking out of the `Reader` monad.

You start with a `Reader` and then you extract from a `Seq` so this cannot be translated in a `flatMap/map` chain within the `Reader` structure.

Comment: Right, so I need to stuff the `record <- all` inside a dummy monad?

Comment: You need to make sure that things that are on the right side of the `<-` return a `UOW[_]`.

Comment: So, I dumped the 2nd and 3rd steps into an inline UOW and it seems to work but it's quite ugly and senseless... is this perchance "lifting"?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure this is the best place to put a reader monad at work. Normally I would use it if I have to chain subsequent reads from the same "bag" (e.g. a bag can be a DB, or a config file). I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here more with a reader monad. Lifting is mapping a function `A => B` into another function `F[A] => F[B]` and this leads to the natural definition of  `F` as a functor.